# URL issue retrieving Custom Post Types using Backbone JS API

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, javascript, rest-api, backbone

I have a Custom Post Type called `pronews`. I registered it with `show_in_rest` enabled. I'm using WordPress 5.5.

I then have this code:

```js
export const ProPost  = wp.api.models.Post.extend( {
    urlRoot: wpApiSettings.root + 'wp/v2/pronews',
    defaults: {
        type: 'pronews',
    },
} );
export const ProPosts = wp.api.collections.Posts.extend( {
    url: wpApiSettings.root + 'wp/v2/pronews',
    model: ProPost,
} );

const post = new ProPost( {id: 2454} );

console.log( post );
console.log( 'post urlRoot:' + post.urlRoot );
console.log( 'post url:' + post.url );

post.fetch().then( ( response ) => {
    console.log( response )
}, ( why ) => {
    console.log( why.responseJSON.code )
} );

// Double check that the endpoint is functionnal
fetch( wpApiSettings.root + 'wp/v2/pronews/2454' )
    .then( blob => blob.json() )
    .then( ( response ) => {
        console.log( response.id );
    } );
```

In the console I first get:

```js
{…}
​_changing: false
​_pending: false
​_previousAttributes: Object { type: "pronews", id: 2454 }
​attributes: Object { type: "pronews", id: 2454 }
​changed: Object {  }
​cid: "c3"
​id: 2454
​<prototype>: Object { urlRoot: "https://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/pronews", defaults: {…}, constructor: i()
 }
ProNews.js:17:9
```

```js
post urlRoot:https://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/pronews ProNews.js:18:9
post url:function(){var e=a.get("apiRoot")+a.get("versionString")+("me"===i?"users/me":i);return _.isUndefined(this.get("id"))||(e+="/"+this.get("id")),e} ProNews.js:19:9
```

But the Backbone API's request is done to the wrong `urlRoot` :

```js
XHRGET https://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/2454 [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 340ms]
rest_post_invalid_id
```

For debugging, the result of the second HTTP Request using `window.fetch`, shows that the endpoint for the Custom Post Type exists and is functional:

```js
XHRGET https://localhost/wp-json/wp/v2/pronews/2454 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 587ms]
2454
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you don't have to extend the `Post` model (`wp.api.models.Post`) or `Posts` collection (`wp.api.collections.Posts`) because the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/) says:

> you will get new models and collections when you [add REST API support to your custom post type](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-rest-api-support-for-custom-content-types/)

And that means, your custom post type will be automatically added to the `wp.api.models` and `wp.api.collections` list, i.e. `wp.api.models.<key>` and `wp.api.collections.<key>` whereby `<key>` is the *post type slug **in camel case***. So in your case, the key would be `Pronews` — or `ProNews` if the post type was `pro-news`.

Therefore, all you need to do to get access to the model/collection (or simply put, posts) is:

```js
// Access one model (a single post). ID is required.
const post = new wp.api.models.Pronews( { id: 57 } );

// Access a collection (multiple models/posts).
const posts = new wp.api.collections.Pronews();
```

Easy, eh? :) ( And if you want, you may extend your post type's model/collection.. e.g. `const ProPost = wp.api.models.Pronews.extend( ... )` )